# Were there 600,000 Israelites, or 600 "soldiers"?

Tags: hebrew, hebrew-bible

This question is a follow-up from [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/13957/1548) where a user on Christianity.SE claimed that the Hebrew words for "thousand" and "soldier" were mixed up in the transcription and translation of the Bible, presenting an extreme exaggeration in the number of Israelites in Egypt and in the Wilderness.

Is this correct?